# iTunes iOS download error / won't install

Tags: ios, delphi, installation, itunes, delphi-xe5

Noone including myself can download any apps from my iTunes account except the **first app** I released.

They all go through automated testing + apple verification, however when I (and other) try to download through my phone I get error message (translated from Danish)

> can not download
>
> can not install

Here is he log:

```
Jul  1 09:29:38 MyIPhone4IOS7 AppStore[148] <Warning>: [SSMetricsEventController] Direct-access controller is calling through XPC to flush Unreported Events
Jul  1 09:30:35 MyIPhone4IOS7 backboardd[28] <Notice>: Posting 'com.apple.iokit.hid.displayStatus' notifyState=0
Jul  1 09:30:35 MyIPhone4IOS7 kernel[0] <Debug>: ALS: AppleARMBacklight::setBacklightEnableGated 0 (set level to 0x1c8)
Jul  1 09:30:35 MyIPhone4IOS7 kernel[0] <Debug>: ALS: AppleARMBacklight::handleMessageGated - framebufferState -> 0
Jul  1 09:30:35 MyIPhone4IOS7 kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleMultitouchN1SPI: updating power statistics
Jul  1 09:30:35 MyIPhone4IOS7 kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleKeyStore::device_state_transition: Device Lock call: lockstate=0, locknow=0
Jul  1 09:30:35 MyIPhone4IOS7 SpringBoard[34] <Warning>: [MPUSystemMediaControls] Disabling lock screen media controls updates for screen turning off.
Jul  1 09:30:35 MyIPhone4IOS7 SpringBoard[34] <Warning>: [MPUNowPlayingController] Not registered for now playing notifications. Ignoring call to -unregisterForNotifications.
Jul  1 09:30:35 MyIPhone4IOS7 SpringBoard[34] <Error>: MKBDeviceLockAssertion: MKBDeviceLockAssertion (asserttype:4)
Jul  1 09:30:35 MyIPhone4IOS7 SpringBoard[34] <Notice>: (Note ) MC: Locking device.
Jul  1 09:30:35 MyIPhone4IOS7 backboardd[28] <Notice>: MultitouchHID: detection mode: 0->255
Jul  1 09:30:36 MyIPhone4IOS7 kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleKeyStore::device_state_transition: Device Lock call: lockstate=5, locknow=0
Jul  1 09:30:36 MyIPhone4IOS7 SpringBoard[34] <Error>: __MKBAssertionFinalize: __MKBAssertionFinalize(0x15bef5c0)
Jul  1 09:30:36 MyIPhone4IOS7 SpringBoard[34] <Notice>: (Note ) MC: Locking device.
Jul  1 09:30:36 MyIPhone4IOS7 SpringBoard[34] <Warning>: [MPUSystemMediaControls] Updating supported commands for now playing application.
Jul  1 09:30:36 MyIPhone4IOS7 AppStore[148] <Warning>: [SSMetricsEventController] Direct-access controller is calling through XPC to flush Unreported Events
Jul  1 09:30:37 MyIPhone4IOS7 AppStore[148] <Warning>: [SSMetricsEventController] Direct-access controller is calling through XPC to flush Unreported Events
Jul  1 09:30:37 MyIPhone4IOS7 AppStore[148] <Warning>: [SSMetricsEventController] Direct-access controller is calling through XPC to flush Unreported Events
Jul  1 09:31:04 MyIPhone4IOS7 SpringBoard[34] <Warning>: Killing com.example.newapp for app installation
Jul  1 09:31:04 MyIPhone4IOS7 itunesstored[100] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installing app for existing placeholder LSApplicationProxy: com.example.newapp (Placeholder)
Jul  1 09:31:04 MyIPhone4IOS7 itunesstored[100] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Creating installProgressForApplication:LSApplicationProxy: com.example.newapp (Placeholder) withPhase:1
Jul  1 09:31:04 MyIPhone4IOS7 lsd[77] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Updating installPhase for parent <NSProgress: phase=Loading; state=Active; fractionCompleted=0.590000> to 1
Jul  1 09:31:04 MyIPhone4IOS7 installd[63] <Notice>: 0x303000 handle_install_for_ls: Install of "/var/mobile/Media/Downloads/6792080868625274691/-5383248391545872630" requested by itunesstored
Jul  1 09:31:04 MyIPhone4IOS7 installd[63] <Error>: 0x303000 peruse_package: App info dict loaded from "/var/tmp/install_staging.Nio6Yc/foo_extracted/Payload/new.app" did not have bundle identifier
Jul  1 09:31:04 MyIPhone4IOS7 installd[63] <Error>: 0x303000 stage_package: Could not peruse package at /var/tmp/install_staging.Nio6Yc/foo_extracted
Jul  1 09:31:04 MyIPhone4IOS7 itunesstored[100] <Error>: 0x1ab1000 MobileInstallationInstallForLaunchServices: failed with -1
Jul  1 09:31:04 MyIPhone4IOS7 itunesstored[100] <Warning>: ERROR: MobileInstallationInstallForLaunchServices returned nil
Jul  1 09:31:04 MyIPhone4IOS7 lsd[77] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installation failed for app com.example.newapp
Jul  1 09:31:04 MyIPhone4IOS7 installd[63] <Error>: 0x303000 MobileInstallationInstall_Server: Could not stage the package
Jul  1 09:31:04 MyIPhone4IOS7 itunesstored[100] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installPhaseFinishedForProgress: com.example.newapp.Installing - <NSProgress: phase=Installing; state=Failed; fractionCompleted=0.000000> called, removing progress from cache
Jul  1 09:31:04 MyIPhone4IOS7 lsd[77] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installation failed for app com.example.newapp
Jul  1 09:31:04 MyIPhone4IOS7 itunesstored[100] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installPhaseFinishedForProgress: com.example.newapp.Loading - <NSProgress: phase=Loading; state=Failed; fractionCompleted=1.000000> called, removing progress from cache
Jul  1 09:31:04 MyIPhone4IOS7 installd[63] <Error>: 0x303000 handle_install_for_ls: API failed
Jul  1 09:31:06 MyIPhone4IOS7 SpringBoard[34] <Error>: MKBDeviceLockAssertion: MKBDeviceLockAssertion (asserttype:4)
Jul  1 09:31:06 MyIPhone4IOS7 kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleKeyStore::device_state_transition: Device Lock call: lockstate=5, locknow=0
Jul  1 09:31:06 MyIPhone4IOS7 SpringBoard[34] <Error>: __MKBAssertionFinalize: __MKBAssertionFinalize(0x15bc24b0)
Jul  1 09:31:06 MyIPhone4IOS7 SpringBoard[34] <Notice>: (Note ) MC: Locking device.
Jul  1 09:31:09 MyIPhone4IOS7 backboardd[28] <Notice>: Posting 'com.apple.iokit.hid.displayStatus' notifyState=1
Jul  1 09:31:09 MyIPhone4IOS7 SpringBoard[34] <Warning>: [MPUSystemMediaControls] Enabling lock screen media controls updates for screen turning on.
Jul  1 09:31:09 MyIPhone4IOS7 SpringBoard[34] <Error>: MKBDeviceLockAssertion: MKBDeviceLockAssertion (asserttype:4)
Jul  1 09:31:10 MyIPhone4IOS7 kernel[0] <Debug>: set_crc_notification_state 0
Jul  1 09:31:10 MyIPhone4IOS7 backboardd[28] <Notice>: MultitouchHID: detection mode: 255->5 (deferring until bootloaded)
Jul  1 09:31:10 MyIPhone4IOS7 SpringBoard[34] <Error>: __MKBAssertionFinalize: __MKBAssertionFinalize(0x15bb5e30)
Jul  1 09:31:10 MyIPhone4IOS7 SpringBoard[34] <Notice>: (Note ) MC: Locking device.
Jul  1 09:31:10 MyIPhone4IOS7 SpringBoard[34] <Warning>: [MPUSystemMediaControls] Updating supported commands for now playing application.
Jul  1 09:31:10 MyIPhone4IOS7 backboardd[28] <Notice>: MultitouchHID: device bootloaded
Jul  1 09:31:10 MyIPhone4IOS7 backboardd[28] <Notice>: MultitouchHID: detection mode: 5->5
Jul  1 09:31:10 MyIPhone4IOS7 SpringBoard[34] <Error>: MKBDeviceLockAssertion: MKBDeviceLockAssertion (asserttype:4)
Jul  1 09:31:10 MyIPhone4IOS7 SpringBoard[34] <Error>: __MKBAssertionFinalize: __MKBAssertionFinalize(0x159b1e80)
Jul  1 09:31:10 MyIPhone4IOS7 SpringBoard[34] <Notice>: (Note ) MC: Locking device.
Jul  1 09:31:10 MyIPhone4IOS7 kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleKeyStore::device_state_transition: Device Lock call: lockstate=5, locknow=0
Jul  1 09:31:10 MyIPhone4IOS7 kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleKeyStore::device_state_transition: Device Lock call: lockstate=5, locknow=0
Jul  1 09:31:10 MyIPhone4IOS7 kernel[0] <Debug>: ALS: AppleARMBacklight::handleMessageGated - framebufferState -> 1
Jul  1 09:31:10 MyIPhone4IOS7 kernel[0] <Debug>: ALS: AppleARMBacklight::setBacklightEnableGated 1 (set level to 0x656)
Jul  1 09:31:11 MyIPhone4IOS7 SpringBoard[34] <Error>: MKBDeviceLockAssertion: MKBDeviceLockAssertion (asserttype:4)
Jul  1 09:31:11 MyIPhone4IOS7 kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleKeyStore::device_state_transition: Device UnLock call, lockstate=5, transientCnt=1
Jul  1 09:31:11 MyIPhone4IOS7 kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleKeyStore::device_state_transition: Device UnLocked, lockstate=0
Jul  1 09:31:11 MyIPhone4IOS7 backboardd[28] <Notice>: MultitouchHID: detection mode: 5->0
Jul  1 09:31:11 MyIPhone4IOS7 SpringBoard[34] <Error>: __MKBAssertionFinalize: __MKBAssertionFinalize(0x15921630)
Jul  1 09:31:13 MyIPhone4IOS7 AppStore[148] <Warning>: Launch Services: Registering unknown app identifier com.example.oldapp failed
Jul  1 09:31:13 MyIPhone4IOS7 AppStore[148] <Warning>: Launch Services: Unable to find app identifier com.example.oldapp
Jul  1 09:31:14 MyIPhone4IOS7 AppStore[148] <Warning>: Launch Services: Registering unknown app identifier com.example.oldapp failed
Jul  1 09:31:14 MyIPhone4IOS7 AppStore[148] <Warning>: Launch Services: Unable to find app identifier com.example.oldapp
Jul  1 09:31:37 MyIPhone4IOS7 AppStore[148] <Warning>: [SSMetricsEventController] Direct-access controller is calling through XPC to flush Unreported Events
Jul  1 09:32:19 MyIPhone4IOS7 kernel[0] <Debug>: ALS: AppleARMBacklight::setBacklightEnableGated 0 (set level to 0x1c8)
Jul  1 09:32:19 MyIPhone4IOS7 kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleMultitouchN1SPI: updating power statistics
Jul  1 09:32:19 MyIPhone4IOS7 kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleKeyStore::device_state_transition: Device Lock call: lockstate=0, locknow=0
Jul  1 09:32:19 MyIPhone4IOS7 backboardd[28] <Notice>: Posting 'com.apple.iokit.hid.displayStatus' notifyState=0
Jul  1 09:32:19 MyIPhone4IOS7 SpringBoard[34] <Warning>: [MPUSystemMediaControls] Disabling lock screen media controls updates for screen turning off.
Jul  1 09:32:19 MyIPhone4IOS7 SpringBoard[34] <Warning>: [MPUNowPlayingController] Not registered for now playing notifications. Ignoring call to -unregisterForNotifications.
Jul  1 09:32:19 MyIPhone4IOS7 SpringBoard[34] <Error>: MKBDeviceLockAssertion: MKBDeviceLockAssertion (asserttype:4)
Jul  1 09:32:19 MyIPhone4IOS7 SpringBoard[34] <Notice>: (Note ) MC: Locking device.
Jul  1 09:32:19 MyIPhone4IOS7 backboardd[28] <Notice>: MultitouchHID: detection mode: 0->255
Jul  1 09:32:19 MyIPhone4IOS7 kernel[0] <Debug>: ALS: AppleARMBacklight::handleMessageGated - framebufferState -> 0
Jul  1 09:32:19 MyIPhone4IOS7 SpringBoard[34] <Error>: __MKBAssertionFinalize: __MKBAssertionFinalize(0x15b775b0)
Jul  1 09:32:19 MyIPhone4IOS7 SpringBoard[34] <Notice>: (Note ) MC: Locking device.
Jul  1 09:32:19 MyIPhone4IOS7 SpringBoard[34] <Warning>: [MPUSystemMediaControls] Updating supported commands for now playing application.
Jul  1 09:32:19 MyIPhone4IOS7 kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleKeyStore::device_state_transition: Device Lock call: lockstate=5, locknow=0
Jul  1 09:32:20 MyIPhone4IOS7 AppStore[148] <Warning>: [SSMetricsEventController] Direct-access controller is calling through XPC to flush Unreported Events
Jul  1 09:32:20 MyIPhone4IOS7 AppStore[148] <Warning>: [SSMetricsEventController] Direct-access controller is calling through XPC to flush Unreported Events
Jul  1 09:32:20 MyIPhone4IOS7 AppStore[148] <Warning>: [SSMetricsEventController] Direct-access controller is calling through XPC to flush Unreported Events
Jul  1 09:32:37 MyIPhone4IOS7 backboardd[28] <Notice>: Posting 'com.apple.iokit.hid.displayStatus' notifyState=1
Jul  1 09:32:37 MyIPhone4IOS7 SpringBoard[34] <Warning>: [MPUSystemMediaControls] Enabling lock screen media controls updates for screen turning on.
Jul  1 09:32:37 MyIPhone4IOS7 SpringBoard[34] <Error>: MKBDeviceLockAssertion: MKBDeviceLockAssertion (asserttype:4)
Jul  1 09:32:37 MyIPhone4IOS7 kernel[0] <Debug>: set_crc_notification_state 0
Jul  1 09:32:37 MyIPhone4IOS7 backboardd[28] <Notice>: MultitouchHID: detection mode: 255->5 (deferring until bootloaded)
Jul  1 09:32:37 MyIPhone4IOS7 SpringBoard[34] <Error>: __MKBAssertionFinalize: __MKBAssertionFinalize(0x15bedd90)
Jul  1 09:32:37 MyIPhone4IOS7 SpringBoard[34] <Notice>: (Note ) MC: Locking device.
Jul  1 09:32:37 MyIPhone4IOS7 SpringBoard[34] <Warning>: [MPUSystemMediaControls] Updating supported commands for now playing application.
Jul  1 09:32:37 MyIPhone4IOS7 backboardd[28] <Notice>: MultitouchHID: device bootloaded
Jul  1 09:32:37 MyIPhone4IOS7 backboardd[28] <Notice>: MultitouchHID: detection mode: 5->5
Jul  1 09:32:37 MyIPhone4IOS7 SpringBoard[34] <Error>: MKBDeviceLockAssertion: MKBDeviceLockAssertion (asserttype:4)
Jul  1 09:32:37 MyIPhone4IOS7 SpringBoard[34] <Error>: __MKBAssertionFinalize: __MKBAssertionFinalize(0x15a52bc0)
Jul  1 09:32:37 MyIPhone4IOS7 SpringBoard[34] <Notice>: (Note ) MC: Locking device.
Jul  1 09:32:38 MyIPhone4IOS7 kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleKeyStore::device_state_transition: Device Lock call: lockstate=5, locknow=0
Jul  1 09:32:38 MyIPhone4IOS7 kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleKeyStore::device_state_transition: Device Lock call: lockstate=5, locknow=0
Jul  1 09:32:38 MyIPhone4IOS7 kernel[0] <Debug>: ALS: AppleARMBacklight::handleMessageGated - framebufferState -> 1
Jul  1 09:32:38 MyIPhone4IOS7 kernel[0] <Debug>: ALS: AppleARMBacklight::setBacklightEnableGated 1 (set level to 0x656)
Jul  1 09:32:39 MyIPhone4IOS7 SpringBoard[34] <Error>: MKBDeviceLockAssertion: MKBDeviceLockAssertion (asserttype:4)
Jul  1 09:32:39 MyIPhone4IOS7 kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleKeyStore::device_state_transition: Device UnLock call, lockstate=5, transientCnt=1
Jul  1 09:32:39 MyIPhone4IOS7 kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleKeyStore::device_state_transition: Device UnLocked, lockstate=0
Jul  1 09:32:39 MyIPhone4IOS7 backboardd[28] <Notice>: MultitouchHID: detection mode: 5->0
Jul  1 09:32:39 MyIPhone4IOS7 SpringBoard[34] <Error>: __MKBAssertionFinalize: __MKBAssertionFinalize(0x15ba69f0)
Jul  1 09:32:40 MyIPhone4IOS7 AppStore[148] <Warning>: Launch Services: Registering unknown app identifier com.example.oldapp failed
Jul  1 09:32:40 MyIPhone4IOS7 AppStore[148] <Warning>: Launch Services: Unable to find app identifier com.example.oldapp
Jul  1 09:32:43 MyIPhone4IOS7 AppStore[148] <Warning>: Launch Services: Registering unknown app identifier com.example.oldapp failed
Jul  1 09:32:43 MyIPhone4IOS7 AppStore[148] <Warning>: Launch Services: Unable to find app identifier com.example.oldapp
Jul  1 09:32:43 MyIPhone4IOS7 AppStore[148] <Warning>: [SSMetricsEventController] Direct-access controller is calling through XPC to flush Unreported Events
Jul  1 09:32:44 MyIPhone4IOS7 AppStore[148] <Warning>: [SSMetricsEventController] Direct-access controller is calling through XPC to flush Unreported Events
Jul  1 09:32:44 MyIPhone4IOS7 AppStore[148] <Warning>: [SSMetricsEventController] Direct-access controller is calling through XPC to flush Unreported Events
Jul  1 09:32:47 MyIPhone4IOS7 lsd[77] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installation ended for app com.example.newapp
Jul  1 09:32:47 MyIPhone4IOS7 itunesstored[100] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Creating installProgressForApplication:LSApplicationProxy: com.example.newapp (Placeholder) withPhase:0
Jul  1 09:32:48 MyIPhone4IOS7 itunesstored[100] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Uninstalling placeholder for app LSApplicationProxy: com.example.newapp (Placeholder)
Jul  1 09:32:48 MyIPhone4IOS7 installd[63] <Notice>: 0x303000 handle_uninstall_for_ls: Uninstall requested by itunesstored
Jul  1 09:32:48 MyIPhone4IOS7 installd[63] <Notice>: 0x303000 MobileInstallationUninstall_Server: Uninstalling com.example.newapp
Jul  1 09:32:48 MyIPhone4IOS7 SpringBoard[34] <Warning>: Killing com.example.newapp for termination assertion
Jul  1 09:32:50 MyIPhone4IOS7 backboardd[28] <Warning>: Launch Services: Registering unknown app identifier com.example.newapp failed
Jul  1 09:32:50 MyIPhone4IOS7 backboardd[28] <Warning>: Launch Services: Unable to find app identifier com.example.newapp
Jul  1 09:32:50 MyIPhone4IOS7 lsd[77] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Updating identifier store
Jul  1 09:32:50 MyIPhone4IOS7 itunesstored[100] <Warning>: LaunchServices: clearing created progress for com.example.newapp
Jul  1 09:33:52 MyIPhone4IOS7 backboardd[28] <Notice>: Posting 'com.apple.iokit.hid.displayStatus' notifyState=0
Jul  1 09:33:52 MyIPhone4IOS7 kernel[0] <Debug>: ALS: AppleARMBacklight::setBacklightEnableGated 0 (set level to 0x1c8)
Jul  1 09:33:52 MyIPhone4IOS7 kernel[0] <Debug>: ALS: AppleARMBacklight::handleMessageGated - framebufferState -> 0
Jul  1 09:33:52 MyIPhone4IOS7 kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleMultitouchN1SPI: updating power statistics
Jul  1 09:33:52 MyIPhone4IOS7 kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleKeyStore::device_state_transition: Device Lock call: lockstate=0, locknow=0
Jul  1 09:33:52 MyIPhone4IOS7 SpringBoard[34] <Warning>: [MPUSystemMediaControls] Disabling lock screen media controls updates for screen turning off.
Jul  1 09:33:52 MyIPhone4IOS7 SpringBoard[34] <Warning>: [MPUNowPlayingController] Not registered for now playing notifications. Ignoring call to -unregisterForNotifications.
Jul  1 09:33:52 MyIPhone4IOS7 SpringBoard[34] <Error>: MKBDeviceLockAssertion: MKBDeviceLockAssertion (asserttype:4)
Jul  1 09:33:52 MyIPhone4IOS7 SpringBoard[34] <Notice>: (Note ) MC: Locking device.
Jul  1 09:33:52 MyIPhone4IOS7 backboardd[28] <Notice>: MultitouchHID: detection mode: 0->255
Jul  1 09:33:53 MyIPhone4IOS7 SpringBoard[34] <Error>: __MKBAssertionFinalize: __MKBAssertionFinalize(0x15bf5290)
Jul  1 09:33:53 MyIPhone4IOS7 SpringBoard[34] <Notice>: (Note ) MC: Locking device.
Jul  1 09:33:53 MyIPhone4IOS7 SpringBoard[34] <Warning>: [MPUSystemMediaControls] Updating supported commands for now playing application.
Jul  1 09:33:53 MyIPhone4IOS7 kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleKeyStore::device_state_transition: Device Lock call: lockstate=5, locknow=0
```

It does seem there somehow is a reference to an old app **com.example.oldapp** one place which is another app of mine already in app store. **com.example.newapp** is the one I am trying to submit. Interestingly **com.example.oldapp** is the first app I ever released.

Here is a list of things I have tried:

- Recreated **all** certificates and provision files from scratch. (i.e. removed everything, I renewed account so it was necessary anyway)
- Started new projects from scratch.
- Tried using a hex editors to search through the files in the .ipa (submitted in application uploader) for e.g. wrong app IDs, text strings or anything that could hint something wrong was inlcuded in the .ipa file.
- Compared all files line-by-line (including provisioning profiles, plist ec.) from my working (first) app and all the others (non-downloadable) apps.

Current staus:
I have been in contact wih Apple Developer Technical Support (DTS) who concluded it was not a code error and that I should contact app store support

Personally I have begun to suspect that there is an error when Apple signs the app. Maybe my iOS developer account somehow has an error causing this. I have checked what I could, but I am thinking it could be a "hangover" issue caused by configuration mistakes when I started. maybe something that causes something from the original first app to act as fallback or similar when Apple sign. This is pure guesswork though and rather desperate.

If **anyone** has any ideas of what else to try, please let me know!

**Note** All my apps have unique app IDs and are otherwise configured the same way, so if this was a normal problem, the issue should affect all my apps instead of everyone but my first.

Comment: This may be useful for those of us looking to deploy apps soon. Congratulations on getting it on to the Store! Perhaps if you give us the app name we can download it and try it?

Comment: I will write over Google+ (I can no write it publicly since it is an app for a customer)

Comment: There's plenty of [Google hits on "app does not have a bundle identifier"](https://www.google.com/search?q=app+does+not+have+a+bundle+identifier), one of which [Creating the bundle ID](http://www.aquafadas.com/en/documentation/sample-page/developer-apple-com/creating-the-bundle-id/) may be what you need.

Comment: Most of those turns up to be  about the error "app does not have a valid bundle identifier". Also, most of them happen about application uploader throws back validation errors which is not what happens in my case. That said, I got no better idea myself, so I will make sure to double check everything again tomorrow. (But I have already spent quite a few hours double checking everything line by line multiple times even including inspecting the provisioning files)

Comment: Could it be the settings on the iTunes Connect? Eg: Country restriction? Or the settings of your provisioning certificates. Have you tried to restart your iPhone and download it? How about testing on downloading using 3G vs Wifi? We definitely need more info from your before able to help you.

Comment: @Ricky I have tried everything I could including those you mention and all the things should be okay. (I upvoted your comment though)

Answer (score 1):

- If you are using iOS 8 for developers (in that case), and your app has been approved by apple, this might be the problem. Try downloading it on an iOS 7 device, see if you get the same error.
- If you are still using iOS 7, Then it might be an app store problem, not your. In this case contact apple through the developers portal.
- Regarding the bundle identifier, in Xcode, click on your app's target, go to the info Info tab, and check that the bundle identifier is there. It sounds you might have deleted it by mistake. If its not there or if the error persists, copy the bundle identifier that appears on itunes connect for your app and paste it in the bundle identifier key in the info tab.

This are the solutions I was able to make from the description of your problem, if its different please tell me so I can help you!

Comment: I awarded this the bounty, but I still do no have a solution, but I will reurn when I have. I am using/testing out everything people suggest here. Thanks!